# Slanted left border on multiple line text element

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm looking to make the this:

[image]

I've tried this (using Tailwind CSS):

```
<div class="border-l-8 border-flourish-500 pl-12">
   <h1 class="text-5xl text-white font-black leading-none uppercase italic">Our<br/>
     <span class="text-flourish-500">Store</span></h1>
</div>
```

But it gets hacky when trying to add the slant (add a 5° transform on the main div and then -5° on the text.)

I also thought using ::before might work but so far haven't been able to get to stretch the (variable) height of the H1.

Does anyone have a clean(er) way of making something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is not very straight forward and it's a bit tricky but by **applying `skew` to one of `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element, this can be achievable** (There are several ways to do it but this one is preferred).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #141e41;
}

.story {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1;
}

.story > span {
  color: #60b4e0;
}

.story::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -80px;
  border: #60b4e0 solid 5px;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="story">
      OUR
      <span><br>STORY</span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Here is the live demo: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/smalikss/pen/qBOYjVa)

Comment: Thanks for that, looks good! Unfortunately, it still has the height declared so won't work in all situations but going to still mark it as an answer because technically worked. 

Comment: Just set height: 100%

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is probably `transform: skew()`. Made a working example below.

```css
.skew::before {
  content: "";
  border: #000 solid 5px;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="skew">
  A nice title
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, declaring the height means it doesn't work over multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Tailwind classes to do the job, and it is working well.

```html
<div class="border-l-8 border-flourish-500 transform -skew-x-6">
   <h2 class="h2 text-white ml-10 mb-8 transform skew-x-6">Find Your<br/>
     <span class="text-flourish-500">Chapter</span>
   </h2>
</div>
```